# jQuery: Save unload events for later use

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, event-handling

I want to save an unload event to execute it later on. For example:

```
// on unload do nothing but safe the event
jQuery(window).unload(function() {
            // TODO safe the unload event here somehow
            // unloadEvent = this;
            return false;
});
```

Later, another piece of code should be able to perform the previously saved event, for example like this:

```
function finallyUnload() {
        // TODO
        // unloadEvent.perform();
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

## Update

My browser window is communicating with a Java Selenium application and needs to wait until it received the information about the unload event and how it happened. When that's the case, the unload event can be executed.

I understood that unload events cannot be delayed or stopped, so i got another idea. What about intercepting all clicks on links with href and buttons, also submissions of forms. Then i manually set `window.location` to the desired URL or submit the form. Could that work?

Comment: `I want to save an unload event to execute it later on`. Could you please define `later on`? There's not much javascript executing on your page after the `unload` event. Well, actually there could be, but not on the same page as the user is leaving it.

Comment: You can't cancel an `unload` event, period.

Comment: @Darin: my browser window is communicating with a Java Selenium application and needs to wait till it received the information about the unload event and how it happened. When that's the case, the unload event can be executed.

Comment: @SLaks: i dont want to cancel it, i want to postpone it

Comment: You can't do that either.  `return false` won't do anything.

Comment: what about e.preventDefault()? http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I intercept all `click` and `submit` events and save them for later use after my application pulled the needed event data.

But it does not work in all cases: [Intercept JavaScript unload events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350843/intercept-javascript-unload-events)